# Chain of length $2^{\aleph_0}$ in $ (P(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

How can I find a *chain* of length $2^{\aleph_0}$ in $ (P(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq )$.

The only chain I have in mind is

$$\{\{0 \},\{0,1 \},\{0,1,2 \},\{ 0,1,2,3\},...,\{\mathbb{N} \} \}$$

But the chain is of length $\aleph_0$, right?

Comment: Hint: $\Bbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182145/finding-an-uncountable-chain-of-subsets-the-integers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Hint:** Since there is a bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ there is an order isomorphism between their power sets with inclusion.

Now think about Dedekind-cuts.

---

Also, your chain is indeed countable.

Comment: Amazing! Maybe magic is in the eyes of ignorant beholders like me.

Comment: @Metta: It's a bunch of tricks, and you learn them with time. :-)

Comment: And this trick's really pretty natural: it's hard to directly solve this for $\Bbb{N}$, because $\Bbb{N}$ is in some vague sense too "small". So replace $\Bbb{N}$ with a "bigger" countable set and the problem becomes easier.