# Is this enough for a set to be countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given set $\mathcal{P}$ of subsets of a countable set $X$. 
For each $A, B \in \mathcal{P}$ it is given that $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$.
Does it follow that $\mathcal{P}$ is countable itself?

Comment: More or less a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253192/chain-of-length-2-aleph-0in-p-mathbbn-subseteq

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $A_x=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<x\}$.