# Partial order on $\langle P(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq\rangle$ contains continuum-size chains and anti-chains

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Consider the partially ordered set $\langle P(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq\rangle$.

I am trying to show two things:

(a) There exists a chain $C$ such that $|C|=\mathfrak{c}$.

(b) There exists an anti-chain $A$ such that $|A|=\mathfrak{c}$.

Can you help me with this ? It seems to be fairly hard.

Comment: What is $\mathfrak c$? What is a chain? An anti-chain? For a), is it enough to show that there exists a chain that is not countable?

Comment: Instead of $\mathbb{N}$ use $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @OrlandoMarigliano This is standard terminology and notation in set theory. A *chain* in a partial order is a set of elements of the partial order, any two of which are comparable; similarly, an antichain is a set of elements *no* two of which are comparable (interestingly a different meaning is given when talking about [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics))). And $\mathfrak{c}$ denotes the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: oops, I accidentally assumed the continuum hypothesis in editing this. Fixed now.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253192, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182145

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: You can replace $\Bbb N$ with any other countably infinite set $S$: just use a bijection between $S$ and $\Bbb N$ to transfer subsets of $S$ to corresponding subsets of $\Bbb N$.

- For **(a)** consider the subsets of $\Bbb Q$ that are the left halves of Dedekind cuts. That is, for each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $A_x=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q\le x\}$, and consider the sets $A_x$.
- For **(b)** consider the almost disjoint families of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/278840/12042).

Comment: Be more precisely, please

Comment: There is an easier way to do b).

Comment: @HaskellFun: I expanded it a little; I really can’t say much more than that without actually doing the problem for you.